# Database Schema Treeview PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to create a treeview (ideally using bootstrap) from a MYSQL database table that is essentially a data dictionary structure. Every example I have seen creates a parentid in order to create the json/array input for the treeview however my data structure has all of the hierarchy levels on each line.

The hierarchy would be:

- Database

  - Schemas

    - Tables
- Database

  - Schemas

    - Tables

My database table has 3 columns... database, schema, and table. Each row has all three attributes, so the full hierarchy. What makes this a bit more tricky is the same schema and table can exist in multiple databases.

Any ideas for how I should go about approaching this?

Or perhaps as mentioned below how would I go from an array to a nested array of JavaScript objects that is the input of a treeview?

Here is the php for creating the array:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM MyTable');
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

[Database Structure and Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP3i7.png)

Comment: What exactly is the challenge here? Just query your table and load the data into an in-memory data structure(assuming the data does not exceed a reasonable amount) that matches your definitions(a multidimensional associative array would suffice). You would just then iterate through each level(effectively 3 nested loops) and print the hierarchy. This seems fairly straightforward to me. I think you will have better luck with an answer if you elaborate on the specific problems you see with implementing it.

Comment: I guess my question from there would be how to go from an array in PHP to a nested array of JavaScript objects, as that is the required input for a bootstrap treeview.

Comment: So converting a flat, two-dimensional array(i.e [["database", "schema", "table"], ["database", "schema", "table"], ...]) to an associative array with "database" and "schema" as keys referencing an indexed array of tables, correct? I can answer that.

Comment: When I use json_encode for the php array I get this structure ( [{"database":"Company 1","schema":"Production","object":"Brands"},{"database":"Company 1","schema":"Production","object":"Categories"}] ).... so I think it just needs to be converted into nested json instead of the array of json strings it is now.

Comment: Right. I understand your question now. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to iterate through all rows and insert them into an appropriate map(associative array) in order to "inflate" the data structure.

Something like this:

```php
//Fetch all rows from database into $result
$databases=[];
foreach($result as $row){
    $database=$row["database"];
    $schema=$row["schema"];
    $table=$row["object"];
    if(!array_key_exists($database, $databases))
        $databases[$database]=[];
    if(!array_key_exists($schema, $databases[$database]))
        $databases[$database][$schema]=[];
    array_push($databases[$database][$schema], $table);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, much appreciated!